# append a string to an array of string in C

Tags: c

I have `char **argv={"ls","-l","/bin"}`, and I want to make it a string array which contais `"ls","-l","/bin", (char *)NULL`. I have tried `argv={*argv,(char *)NULL};`, but the compiler told me 'expected expression before '{' token'. What should i do to get it?
BTW, can I use "{}" for declaration of a string array?

Comment: then what if i don't know what's in argv? what if it is input by user?

Comment: I think the `argv` being referred to here is their own, and they are writing a shell.

Comment: Are you aware that the standard requires that `argv[argc]` is a null pointer? (C99, §5.1.2.2.1/2).

Answer (score 0):

write

```
char const *argv[] = { "ls", "-l", "/bin", NULL };
```

When you want to add other arguments conditionally, you can add dummy arguments and fill them on demand:

```
/* the '23' depends on the number of conditions evaluated below */
char const *argv[23] = { [0] = "ls", [1] = "-l", [2] = "/bin" };
size_t idx = 3;

if (user_wants_a)
     argv[idx++] = "-a";
```

When user can add an arbitrary amount of data, you will have to allocate argv[] dynamically:

```
char const **argv = calloc(<number-of-elements>, sizeof argv[0]);

argv[0] = "ls";
argv[1] = "-l";
...
```

and enlarge it on demand:

```
new_argv = realloc(argv, <new-number-of-elements> * sizeof argv[0]));
BUG_ON(!new_argv);
argv = new_argv;
```

Comment: then what if i don't know what's in argv? what if it is input by user?

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing values into the array from user input, You have probably allocated your array in one of two ways:

1. On the stack: `char *argv[MAX_ARGS];`
2. On the heap: `char **argv = malloc( num_args * sizeof(char*) );`

In both cases, lets say the array is filled with `num_args` values and you want to stick a NULL on the end.  In the first case, provided `MAX_ARGS` is larger than `num_args+1`, you can simply do this:

```
argv[num_args] = NULL;
```

In the second case, it's a bit trickier because the array is only just large enough.  In this case, you need to reallocate it first:

```
argv = realloc( argv, (num_args+1) * sizeof(char*) );
if( argv ) argv[num_args] = NULL;
```

There is a third case I didn't consider.  That is where `argv` is the one that was actually supplied to your `main` function.  In this case, you should *not* `realloc`.  Instead, make a copy of the array:

```
char *argv2 = malloc( argv, (num_args+1) * sizeof(char*) );
if( argv2 ) {
    memcpy( argv2, argv, num_args * sizeof(char*) );
    argv2[num_args] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: then what if i don't know the length of argv? i mean it is input by user

Comment: Can you clarify which of the cases we're dealing with?  In the first two cases, you parsed the user input yourself and so you could count.  In the third case, it was supplied to `main` along with `argc` which contains the count.